# Unir dos tablas SQL que no tienen llave foranea

Tags: sql-server-2012

Que tal amigos, estoy ayudando en un proyecto en Laravel con una base de datos SQL bastante mal hecha, en fin...

Tengo Tabla1 con un campo llamado Codigo y Tabla2 con el campo llamado Codigo, el problema radica en que debo unir las tablas mediante el campo Codigo, pero el contenido del campo Codigo de cada tabla es distinto, ejemplo:

**Tabla1.Codigo = 14EPR0199Y -
Tabla2.Codigo = 02 030 005 14EPR0199Y**

¿Como puedo unir las dos tablas por Codigo?

Comment: puedes dar mas especificacion sobre el codigo que tiene en comun para realizar el join que haz pensado , agrega un ejemplo de la tabla 1 y tabla 2 con los datos minimos y como quieres tu resultado

Comment: es siempre el código de tabla1 un string de 10 caracteres?, siempre está al final del código de de la tabla2?

Comment: Codigo de Tabla1 es un string de 11 caracteres, Codigo de Tabla 2 es un string de 22 caracteres y los 11 últimos son los mismos de Codigo de Tabla1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta asi :

```
Select * from Tabla1 t1
    join Tabla2 t2
        on Left(t1.Codigo,10) = Right(t2.Codigo,10)
```

Hacerlo, puedes hacerlo, no vas a poder optimizar la consulta asi tengas indices sobre los campos Codigo ya que las funciones LEFT y RIGHT no lo permitirán, pero si son tablas pequeñas, no deberias tener problemas.

Comment: ¡Funciono!. Gracias!!!